# Windows Update 0x80070643 - .NET Framework Corruption

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework

When updating SQL security, error 0x80070643. What I've done so far:

- DISM and SFC
- .NET Framework Repair tools
- Windows built-in update troubleshooter
- Rename SoftwareDistribution
- Clear/Reset Catroot2
- Reset Windows Update components manually per Windows Update - Additional resources - Windows Deployment | Microsoft Docs
- Reinstalled .NET Framework
- Rebooted in safe mode with networking

No change at this point. Any ideas? Please do not say DISM and SFC. This is not an issue where slapping a manual install is the point. This is an attempt to fully resolve, not Band-Aid the problem and allow it to fester. Thanks!

- Please note: I've rebooted. Other updates installed ~2 weeks ago with no issues.

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall .NET Framework on Windows 10 when a .NET Framework installer does not exist for Windows 10?  What exactly makes you think this issue is a .NET Framework issue?  [Edit] your question and provide the output to `sc.exe queryex SQLPBDMS`

Comment: When all the above happens without success: 1. Try a new, test Windows User Profile. 2. If not a profile error run a Windows 10 Repair, first with Keep Everything, then if no luck Keep only Data